Custom WebView With Loading Indicator - Infinite Reload Cycle
I created the below custom WebView for my app - the goal is to show a loading indicator until the content is loaded successfully.
Everything works fine when
//            if isLoading {
//               ProgressView()
//                   .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .blue))
//                   .scaleEffect(1.5)
//            }

is commented out - apart from the loading indicator showing. However, when I uncomment this code, the page continues to infinitely refresh, with an error "Something went wrong and the page could not load".  I'm testing this with a Stripe subscription management page (not sure if relevant to the issue). I noticed the Coordinator methods continue to be called in a cycle.
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var url: URL
    var token: String
    @Binding var isLoading: Bool

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        return webView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.addValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        uiView.load(request)
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: WebView

        init(_ parent: WebView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            self.parent.isLoading = true
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            self.parent.isLoading = false
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
            self.parent.isLoading = false
        }
    }
}

struct DismissibleWebView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    let url: URL
    let fetchToken: Bool
    
    @State private var token: String?
    @State private var errorMessage: String?
    @State private var isLoading = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                if let token = token, fetchToken {
                    WebView(url: url, token: token, isLoading: $isLoading)
                } else {
                    WebView(url: url, token: "", isLoading: $isLoading)
                }
                if let errorMessage = errorMessage {
                    Text(errorMessage)
                }
                DismissButton()
            }
//            if isLoading {
//               ProgressView()
//                   .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .blue))
//                   .scaleEffect(1.5)
//            }
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .onAppear {
            if fetchToken {
                fetchAuthToken()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchAuthToken() {
        Task {
            do {
                guard let fetchedToken = await UserService.shared.getToken() else {
                    throw NSError(domain: "TokenError", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Authentication token is missing"])
                }
                token = fetchedToken
            } catch {
                errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
            }
        }
    }
}

